# Difference between depmix and depmixS4 in R?

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I'm experimenting with making a Hidden Markov Model and am drawing upon a paper that used the `depmix` package in R. There is also the `depmixS4` package. I can't seem to find any posts or documentation on the difference between the two packages. Are they they effectively the same or meant for different purposes?

Comment: I don't know. I would contact the maintainer of both and ask ...

Comment: They are meant for the same purpose, the S4 version is a reimplementation of the earlier package. See explanation in the package README for `depmixS4`: https://github.com/cran/depmixS4